# Ring Floodlight - Simple alternative by combining camera and floodlight?

Tags: amazon-echo, digital-cameras, lighting, surveillance-cameras

The Ring Floodlight looked pretty nice, until FakeSpot warned that most of the positive reviews seem to be bogus,  so I've decided to not pursue the commercial product and try to figure out how to get the same functionality otherwise.

Is there a smart motion detection flood light that could IFTTT trigger a camera to start recording?

Or would it be better to keep them separate?  For example a night vision motion detecting camera doing its thing, and a separate dumb motion detecting flood light that just turns on when someone walks past?

(Have just an Amazon Echo but don't think this helps me much).

Ring Camera and Flood Light: [https://amazon.com/Ring-Floodlight-Camera-Motion-Activated-Security/dp/B0722R3WV5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0722R3WV5)

FakeSpot Analysis: http://fakespot.com/product/ring-floodlight-camera-motion-activated-hd-security-cam-with-floodlights-two-way-talk-and-siren-alarm-black

Comment: Product link would help... IFTTT has no guarantee of being fast to react.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane added product link and review quality link.

Comment: I am wondering, how much of annoyance this camera can be if it glares the floodlights because a cat crossed its path.

Comment: I wasn't aware of FakeSport, which says "Our engine has analyzed and discovered that 20.0% of the reviews are reliable". Looking at the Amazon page, there are 7 reviews, of which 4 are bad and 3 are good (from verified purchasers).  1 reviewer has reviwd only a single product, and the other two have reviewed 5 to 10.

Based on this, I am unsure how much I trust FakeSpot's algorithm

Comment: I think this is too broad a question to work here. You have the option of a commercial product (with reviews that say the S/W is borderline), or homebrew something. I think the FakeSpot thing is a red herring, and detracts from the question.

Comment: @Mawg are you looking at the right page?  There are over 300 amazon reviews for the product.  Moreover, if you start to go through each of the 5 star reviews, intuitively many of them seem use language in a way you wouldn't expect normal people to do.  Sure there is reason to question any kind of methodology like this, but it seems to at least be cause for concern.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane on the contrary it's not broad at all.   The question is not commercial product versus homebrew. I've already ruled out the commercial product I'll try to edit to make that more clear. The question which is intended to be narrowly defined, is simply what would be the simplest and most effective homebrew version of such functionality?

Comment: If you consider the commercial product ruled out, then you really should reduce the mention of it to a half sentence, otherwise that distracts from the question it seems you want to address.  Though your question is still relatively broad.

Comment: ik@ChrisStratton I think with the last edit there's not really any room for ambiguity.  What's left is relevant.  If you ask for advice on how write your own operating system, I would certainly want to know why you avoided off the shelf system so that I could advise around any problems or constraints already ncountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The presence of a commercial product which has reviews of varying quality should be a good sign that building something like this from scratch is a non-trivial undertaking. Doing IoT well is hard.

Doing it yourself brings some advantages - you can tune the installation for a specific location, implement your own configuration strategy (most likely cli based), associate with just your home router, etc.

There is no clear answer to which approach is better. Why are you doing this, what skills you you have already, what are you prepared to learn, is security important or can you rely on an ad-hoc implementation providing security through obscurity?

Start by defining your requirements. **Lighting, Motion detection, video capture**. Look at the commercial product you rejected, and decide which aspects of it you need to improve on (this is subjective).

List out some alternative implementations. This could be:

- MCU on each node, handling each aspect with network connection between them
- Raspberry Pi as a central controller with each part connected through (long?) wires.
- Commercial camera, commercial motion detection
- Commercial camera, MCU for motion detection

Trade off the time/cost/performance of these options, and go with whichever *you* prefer. You might find that some of the more low-level approaches are harder but are better documented (since the off-the-shelf components are unlikely to be documented, and will rarely be designed with extensions in mind).

Fundamentally, any working commercial product which satisfies your spec (even if it's got some flaws), will be far easier. Far more research is needed.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if this is an answer, or just a claim that the question is too broad (since the answer is a standard design definition phase checklist).